# Can someone why this expression is evaluating to 40?

Tags: java, math, evaluation

Could some please offer any insight into why this code is outputting 40?
I tried using doubles instead of integers and using the Math.round method to 
make sure it wasn't a precision issue.

```
{
    int x,y ;
    x = ((( 80 + 80 + 80 + 80 + 80) / 500) * 100);
    y = ((x / 2) + (80 / 4) + (80 / 4));
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

I've evaluated the same expression using a calculator and just my own head and 
on all accounts it should be 80! If I'm making a really dumb mistake I'd like to
know but otherwise I'm just curious as to why this is and how to get around it, thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you expect the value of `x` to be, and have you checked that part? Hint: all your operations are in terms of integers, and 400/500 is 0 in integer arithmetic...

Comment: eventually only `(80 / 4) + (80 / 4)` matters

Comment: I think @JonSkeet gets it correct here. In Python, x evaluates to zero on account of it being integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Your x is 0 because:

`( 80 + 80 + 80 + 80 + 80) / 500)` evaluates to 0.

As a result, y becomes  `((0 / 2) + (80 / 4) + (80 / 4))` which evaluates to 40.

Note that when a type int is between 0 and 1, it becomes 0.

**Per comment**, when evaluating 400 / 500, whether or not x is int or double is not relevant, because 400 and 500 is integer so java will apply int arithmetic first, and then move on.

Comment: Well that expression would evaluate to 0.8, then be multiplied by 100, making 80.

Comment: @AaronFisher: Why do you think that expression would evaluate to 0.8? See my comment on your question.

Comment: @AaronFisher `0.8` is not an integer. Intermediate values need to be stored as well.

Comment: 0.8 is "converted" to 0 and then got multiplied by 100.

Comment: Even if I used doubles, like so 
 {
  double x,y ;
  x = ((( 80 + 80 + 80 + 80 + 80) / 500) * 100);
  y = ((x / 2) + (80 / 4) + (80 / 4));
  System.out.println(y);
 } I still only get 40.0, not 80 as I'm expecting

Comment: At least in Python, not sure about Java, you'd need to write 80.0 and 100.0 rather than 80 and 100, which forces the calculation to decimals.

Comment: @AaronFisher when evaluation 400 / 500, whether or not x is int or double is not relevant, because 400 and 500 is integer so java will apply int arithmetic.

Comment: Ohh i see what you're saying @Minjun I'll try switching the values to doubles, thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

x = ((400)/500))* 100

Here 400/500 evaluates to 0 as 400 and 500 are treated as integers

so y = 0 + (80/4) + (80/4) = 40